# Creating a New Project with the Correct Process Template While Keeping the Branching Structure

Tags: tfs

Since our existing project in TFS2010 has a wrong process template, I'm trying to create a new project with the correct process template and use TFS Integration Platform to migrate all work items and version history over to the new one.

However, I'm not quite sure how to migrate all the code over with the current branching structure. Here's our current branching structure:

Main --> Dev

Main --> Release

What I want is after I moved everything from the existing project to new, I can still maintain the same branching structure:

New Main --> New Dev

New Main --> New Release

The questions are:

1. How do I move all the code from the existing project to the new one? Do I branch like this:

   Main --> New Main

   Dev --> New Dev
2. How do I create the relationship between New Main and New Dev?
3. If I use branching like Main --> New Main to bring the code over to the new project, how do I remove the branch relationship between them afterwards (since I'll retire the old project eventually I don't want people to accidentally merge between the old and new project).

Comment: First, can you tell us more about the "wrong process template" part of your question. What do you want to change that makes you want to use a new Process Template?

Comment: The current project is using MSF for Agile Software Development v4.2, which is not the "right" one by our corporate policy. Instead, we should be using Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0

Comment: how do you plan to migrate the work items ? I'm asking that because it may be easier to keep your existing Team Project and change the Work Item Types and SQL Reports than do what you thought about.

Comment: I was planning on using the TFS Integration Plaform tool to migrate all work items and version history over.

Comment: If you have different sets of WIT (work item type) from the source and destination Team Project it'll be very difficult... Do you care about the history of your Work Item? I mean do you want to keep the closed ones or not?

Comment: I do care about the history of my work items. However, at this point I care most about how I'm going to maintain the right branching structure and their relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I give a shot:

**Solution 1:**

SOURCE CONTROL

- Create a new Team Project with the "good" process template
- Create a "New Main" branch derived from "Main"
- Create a "New Dev" branch derived from New Main, so the same for "New Release"
- Merge from "Dev" to "New Dev" accepting the source version in case of conflict. Do the same for "New Release". You **won't** keep the history in the "New Dev/Release" branches, you'll have to look into their base branch when you'll need to.

WORK ITEM

I'd better use Excel to create the Work Items, I'll first set the query that list all the Work Item I want to copy, display the field I care about, then copy the whole thing (with some mapping if needed) into another spreadsheet connected to the new Team Project, then save everything to create the new work items.

You can do that if:
 - you have a reasonable amount of Work Item (you're the one to judge, depending on your motivation ;))
 - you don't care about the history (revisions) of a work item.
 - you're lazy and don't want to use the migration toolkit (or if it fits your needs).

**Solution 2:**

In place upgrade of the Process Template, you can do that, but it's mainly done manually.

SOURCE CONTROL

- Nothing to do, which is the only way to keep everything intact regarding the Source Control (branches relationship, history).

WORK ITEM

- If you want to keep some history use the Excel method I gave you earlier, make sure you got all the Work Items on Excel before adding/changing the WITs
- Delete the all the Work Items. See [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/02/19/tfs-api-part-21-delete-work-item-using-workitemstore-demo-application.aspx).
- Delete the WIT ([tfpt destroywitd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721612.aspx))
- Add the new Work Item Types.
- Create the new ones from Excel if you want to.

SQL REPORTS

- Delete the existing reports
- Add the ones from the new Process Template

**My Take**

I'll go for Solution 2 if Source Control is the most important. Using Excel or the migration toolkit depends on the count of Work Items and if there's a lots of fields I can map...

If you go for Solution 2: **BACK UP YOUR TPC** before doing anything crazy! (I assume you're in TFS 2010)

Comment: I'm afriad neither solution answers the quesiton of how to create a branch relationship as New Main --> New Dev and New Main --> New Release but not Main --> New Main or Dev --> New Dev

Comment: You can't do it, the best way is doing what I told in the Solution 1 or not having to do it by staying in the Team Project.